# Reload parent page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I don't know how possible this is:

I have a page called `index.php` that uses jquery `.load()` to load another page (`page2.php`) into it, in `page2.php` I have a form that uses `$.ajax` to submit the form. Upon successful submission of the form I want to refresh `index.php` and possibly load `page2.php` into the `index.php`.

I have tried all I can and looked around but I still can not get this to work. 
Is this possible and if it is, how do i get this to work.

I hope my question is clear enough?

Comment: ***"I hope my question is clear enough?"*** Nop. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: That is the simplest form i can explain my problem.

Comment: @vicovic Ajax + jQuery could do this, you just have to craft it skillfully. Well, actually after re-reading, if you have already gotten as far as `.load()` and the `$.ajax()` it shouldn't take much more to make it do the rest.

Comment: @Rasclatt I will keep trying

Comment: If I were to do it, I would load the content between the `<body>` of the page as an include so you could load it by itself with ajax after you submit the form. That would "refresh" the page so-to-speak. Then you won't get all the `<!doctype....etc.` html when you reload page 1

Comment: It's also hard to say exactly without seeing everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your callback function you can just reload the page.

```
 $.ajax({
        url:"your_script.php",  
        success:function(data) {
          location.reload();
        }
      });
```

Comment: location.reload(); did the trick for reloading the parent page. too bad i can't upvote your answer cause of my reputation level. Thank you for taking your time to understand my question, I think I can find my way from here.